# Is there a callback for window.scrollTo?

Tags: javascript

I want to call `focus()` on an input after the widow scrolled. I'm using the smooth behavior for the `scrollTo()` method. The problem is the `focus` method cut the smooth behavior. The solution is to call the `focus` function just after the scroll end.

But I can't find any doc or threads speaking about how to detect the end of `scrollTo` method.

```
let el = document.getElementById('input')
let elScrollOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect().top
let scrollOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
let padding = 12
window.scrollTo({
  top: elScrollOffset + scrollOffset - padding,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
// wait for the end of scrolling and then
el.focus()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really know if a call back exists for `scrollTo()` but I think you can try `setTimeout()` only if you know the duration of scrolling!

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but I can't find the scroll duration for the `scrollTo` method :/

Comment: You might want to try [this](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/339) before using your hacky approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know scroll to element is done in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795955/how-to-know-scroll-to-element-is-done-in-javascript)

Comment: @Akaino Thank you for the tip, in vanilla I would just work inside a onscroll listener and watch the page offset. Not so far of what I'm doing.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney, you're right I wasn't looking for scrollIntoView because it isn't well supported yet. I will answer to it too, thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I wrote a generic function based on the solution of George Abitbol, without overwriting window.onscroll:

```js
/**
 * Native scrollTo with callback
 * @param offset - offset to scroll to
 * @param callback - callback function
 */
function scrollTo(offset, callback) {
    const fixedOffset = offset.toFixed();
    const onScroll = function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset.toFixed() === fixedOffset) {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
                callback()
            }
        }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    onScroll()
    window.scrollTo({
        top: offset,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
}
```

Comment: Great function. I think you don't need to call `onScroll()` before `window.scrollTo`, though.

Comment: @caroso1222 Thank you! I added that after some testing, because if the scroll position is already correct the callback won't fire without that call.

Comment: The offset needs to be a whole number for this function to work

Comment: @btjakes To clarify: the `offset` needs to perfectly match the `window.pageYOffset`. In MS Edge `window.pageYOffset` is a float, unlike other browsers. With precision mismatching across browsers, this approach will fail in one or the other unless you're careful with rounding and possibly making a buffer of completion: `if (roundedPageYOffset + 2 >= roundedOffset && roundedOffset >= roundedPageYOffset - 2) { ... }`, rather than just `if (window.pageYOffset === offset) { ... }`

Comment: @btjakes I fixed the number so floats should not be a problem any more. Rounding is a good idea, but might not be precise enough depending on the use case.

Comment: Any ideas why the callback gets called severally after the scroll settles @FabianvonEllerts? Thanks.

Comment: @idrisadetunmbi not really, I never experienced the issue when testing. You can debounce the `onScroll` function to prevent that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51142522/470749 was also helpful for me since I'm triggering scrolling on an infinite page until there are no more results to load, so I think setTimeout is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent function. It noticed that when the `offset` point is close to the end of the document, `window.pageYOffset` and `offset` will never match. Adding `offset = Math.min(offset, documentHeight - viewportHeight);` to the beginning of the script helps. (determining `documentHeight` and `viewportHeight` is another discussion)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the link to the alternative question, I found my exact use case there!

Comment: Need to update `pageYOffset` to `scrollY` because the first one is depreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to achieve what I want but I think it's a bit hacky, isn't it?

```
let el = document.getElementById('input')
let elScrollOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect().top
let scrollOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
let padding = 12
let target = elScrollOffset + scrollOffset - padding
window.scrollTo({
  top: target,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
window.onscroll = e => {
  let currentScrollOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
  // Scroll reach the target
  if (currentScrollOffset === target) {
    el.focus()
    window.onscroll = null // remove listener
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers didn't fully work for me, therefore based on @Fabian von Ellerts answer, I wrote my own solution.

My problems were that :

- The element I was scrolling (and all its parents along the hierarchy) always had a `offsetTop` of 0, so it was not working.
- I needed to scroll a nested element.

Using `getBoundingClientRect` and a container element as reference works :

```js
    const smoothScrollTo = (
        scrollContainer,
        scrolledContent,
        offset,
        callback
    ) => {
        const fixedOffset = (
            scrollContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top + offset
        ).toFixed()
        const onScroll = () => {
            if (
                scrolledContent.getBoundingClientRect().top.toFixed() ===
                fixedOffset
            ) {
                scrollContainer.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
                callback()
            }
        }
        scrollContainer.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
        onScroll()
        scrollContainer.scrollTo({
            top: offset,
            behavior: 'smooth',
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [`scrollend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollend_event), supported everywhere but in Safari, but for what you want you shouldn't even need it, since we're supposed to be able to set the scrolling behavior through CSS, with the `scroll-behavior` rule, this way even `.focus()` should trigger a smooth scroll. Unfortunately, and weirdly enough, only Chrome seems to support this...

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = (evt) => document.querySelector("input").focus();
```

```css
.obstacle {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(black, black 20px, white 20px, white 40px);
  height: 800vh;
}
html { /* The scrolling element */
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

```html
<button>focus target</button>
<div class=obstacle></div>
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make an async version of the @Fabian von Ellerts function, replaced the depreciated `pageYOffset`, and added semicolons :)

```
/**
 * Async scrollTo
 * @param offset - offset to scroll to
 */
async function scrollTo(offset) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fixedOffset = offset.toFixed();
        const onScroll = function () {
                if (window.scrollY.toFixed() === fixedOffset) {
                    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
                    resolve();
                }
            }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        onScroll();
        window.scrollTo({
            top: offset,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
}
```