# ReactJS - Is it possible to adjust the scrollIntoView's function to fit the need of my page's navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m using the `scrollIntoView` function to go from one section to another on my webpage.

I would using some function to adjust the scroll. Currently the scroll make the section appear at top of page but my fixed top menu then hide a part of the section.

To make the section fully displayed on the page after the `scrollIntoView` I have tried to use the function `window.scrollBy` to make the scrollY backs on top of 150px, hence revealing the previously hidden part of the element.

But it fails.

Here my snippet:

```
scrollToElement = (target)=> {
        target.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
        // window.scrollBy(0,-150)
}
```

How adjust my scrollIntoView please?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Perhaps because `scrollBy()` runs immediately after `scrollIntoView()` is invoked with `smooth` behavior and does not wait for it to finish scrolling

Comment: maybe it is possible to get the number of pixel that scrollIntoView would use and push it directly in a scrollTo function using the smooth behavior option?

Comment: If that's indeed the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52292603/1625737

Comment: yes but it is a callback, I will dive to find if it exist a way to adjust directly the pixel that srollIntoView will use like `target.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', pixelAdjustment: y})`