# How to run code after execution of scrollTo() is complete?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to run a function once smooth scrolling to an element in my page is complete. JavaScript's function `scrollTo` doesn't seem to support a fallback function though.

Is it no feasible then?

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: elementLocation,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
myFunction();
```

Comment: already answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292603/is-there-a-callback-for-window-scrollto

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
const position = 500

window.scrollTo({
  top: position,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})

setTimeout(() => console.log('scrolled'), position)
```