# How to use element.scrollIntoView as a promise or observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, scroll, observable

I'm using

```
tab_element.scrollIntoView({
        behavior:'smooth',
        block: 'center',
});
```

to scroll the element at the center
but immediately after this, I need to call `router.navigate`
This is causing the scroll to be interrupted,
so my solution is to do the navigation *after* the scrolling is finished.
Is there a way that I can get a promise or an observable which can be used to call a function after scroll completes?

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your question?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find solution so far  There is no native option to get any callback after scroll finishes.. you can only find solutions which hooks on scroll event like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51142522/861615

Maybe in few years:
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3744
‍♂️

Comment: Was looking for solution for similar problem for my site at https://teipublisher.info/exist/apps/TraveLab/TrilingualTravelab2022-6-13.xml. If I use behavior:'smooth, only one window is synchronized. Hoping this page will be updated with a solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `window.scrollY` is equal to `element.offsetTop` :

```
    function myFunction() {
        const checkEvery = 600;
        const element = document.getElementById('id')


        setTimeout(() => {
            if (window.scrollY === element.offsetTop) { 
                // your code
            } else test();
        }, checkEvery);
    }

    myFunction();
```

Comment: This should be setInterval right?