# How to know `scrollIntoView` will do nothing?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Assume we want to call these 2 function in this specific order:

1. `scrollIntoView`
2. an user-defined function `foo` to be called after `scrollIntoView` finishes (possible scrolling)

Assume we have added an event `'scroll'` callback to call `foo`. Now, the problem is that if the target DOM element is already in view, `scrollIntoView` will not scroll. In that case, event `'scroll'` won't occur.

How do we have `foo` called, whenever the asynchronous function `scrollIntoView` finishes scrolling or doesn't need to scroll at all?

In other words, how do we know function `scrollIntoView` will visually do nothing?

This question is similar to [How to know scroll to element is done in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795955/how-to-know-scroll-to-element-is-done-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if element is in view https://stackoverflow.com/a/125106/19617075 and perform **scrollIntoView** or **foo** based on that.