# How to make the navbar stay fixed when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a navbar that disappears when the user scrolls down, and reappears when they scroll up (the navbar is always visible at the top of the page). However, when a link in the navbar (responsible for redirecting the user to a certain section of the page) is clicked, I would like the navbar to remain visible while the scroll navigates to that section and, only after that, return to its behavior of appearing and disappearing as the scroll.

Code:

```js
// Navbar.jsx

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import NavbarLink from './NavbarLink';

const Navbar = ({ isOpen, toggleMenu, navLinks }) => {
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false);
  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(0);

  const transitionClasses = sticky
    ? `transition-all duration-300 opacity-0 -translate-y-full`
    : `transition-all duration-300 translate-y-0`;

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      scrolling > window.scrollY ? setSticky(false) : setSticky(true);
      setScrolling(window.scrollY);
    });

  }, [scrolling]);

  return (
    <nav className={`${sticky && 'bg-opacity-95'} fixed top-0 bg-white w-full z-50 ${transitionClasses}`}>
      {/* Rest of the code (Not relevant to the question) */}

          {/* Links de Navegação */}
          <div className="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto">
            <ul className="flex flex-row items-center gap-3.5 ml-3 font-medium lg:gap-5">
          <div className='hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto'>
            <ul className='flex flex-row items-center gap-3.5 ml-3 font-medium lg:gap-5'>
              {navLinks.map((link, index) => (
                <NavbarLink key={index} href={link.href} text={link.text} />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

       {/* Rest of the code (Not relevant to the question) */}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

```js
// NavbarLink.jsx 

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

const NavbarLink = ({ href, text }) => {
  if (href.startsWith('/')) {
    return (
      <Link to={href} className={`text-xs lg:text-sm transition duration-300 group`}>
        <li>{text}</li>
        <span className='block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-300 h-0.5 bg-gradient-to-br from-green-500 to-blue-400'></span>
      </Link>
    );
  };

  if (href.startsWith('#')) {
    return (
      <HashLink smooth to={href} className={`text-xs lg:text-sm transition duration-300 group`}>
        <li>{text}</li>
        <span className='block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-300 h-0.5 bg-gradient-to-br from-green-500 to-blue-400'></span>
      </HashLink>
    );
  };
};

export default NavbarLink;
```

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to use `setTimeout`, but I wouldn't want to use that solution because its behavior isn't completely what I want.

**NOTE: my code already produces the effect of appearing and disappearing as you scroll, but it still doesn't support keeping the navbar visible when a link is clicked.**

Answer (score 0):

Since the `HashLink` actually triggers a scroll event, you'd have to clear your window listener until your smooth scroll gets to the anchor link. You can use a boolean state to decide whether or not to activate or deactivate it.

Besides, be careful with `useEffect` when declaring `window` that you delete the listener once the effect is over.

I'm not sure how you intended to use a `setTimeout` function but in order to disable it temporarily you would need something similar (I used one here)

```
// Clicked link state
const [clickedOnNavLink, setClickedOnNavLink] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // Don't enable the scroll event listener if a link was clicked
  if (clickedOnNavLink) return;

  const checkStickyState = () => {
    scrolling > window.scrollY ? setSticky(false) : setSticky(true);
    setScrolling(window.scrollY);
  };
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkStickyState);

  // Remove event listener when finishing the effect
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkStickyState);
}, [scrolling, clickedOnNavLink]);

// Re-enable the window scroll listener event after transition is over
// (I set an arbitrary 800ms timeout value but you can adjust it)
useEffect(() => {
  if (clickedOnNavLink) {
    setTimeout(() => setClickedOnNavLink(false), 800);
  }
}, [clickedOnNavLink]);
```

And in your return statement, add an event around your `NavbarLink` to apply it to your state:

```
{navLinks.map((link, index) => (
  <span key={index} onClick={() => setClickedOnNavLink(true)}>
    <NavbarLink href={link.href} text={link.text} />
  </span>
))}
```

Comment: This works, it was a solution that I had already achieved, but like I said, I don't want to use this solution because it doesn't completely work the way I want. Is there any way to do this without using setTimeout? If necessary, it is possible to change the hashlink to another solution.

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you can detect an end of transition of your HashLink, you could enable and disable the window event listener at the right moment. Otherwise I don't see how to achieve it without a setTimeout if you keep using a component that scrolls with a window scroll event listener. Also, how is the setTimeout not the behaviour you want?

Comment: Otherwise, use another listener when you clicked on the HashLink that detects when the smooth scrolling has ended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795955/how-to-know-scroll-to-element-is-done-in-javascript