How to listen to user scroll event in Vue 3 for a chat app that has an auto scroll?
I am working on a chat app using Vue 3 and composition API. The app uses code that scrolls the last message into view as it is generated like so:
watchEffect(
    () => {
        if (messages.value.length) {
            chatContainer.value.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "end"
            })
        }
    },
    { flush: "post" }
)

This works great, however it is bad UX if the user is trying to read the previous messages and/or is trying to scroll back to the top of the message chain because the auto scroll will drag the user back to the bottom of the screen.
Anyone got any ideas on how I can "disengage" the auto scroll if the user scrolls back up the page? I tried adding an event listener but it didn't work for me.
THanks for any tips. My VUE sandbox is here: sandbox

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795955/how-to-know-scroll-to-element-is-done-in-javascript

For some reason listening to a scroll event did not work


Track User Scroll Direction:

Use a ref to store the current scroll position (previousScrollTop)
In the mounted lifecycle hook, add an event listener for the scroll event on the chat container element.



    <template>
      <div ref="chatContainer" class="chat-container">
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref, onMounted, watchEffect } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
      setup() {
        const chatContainer = ref(null);
        const previousScrollTop = ref(0);
    
        onMounted(() => {
          chatContainer.value.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        });
    
        // ... rest of your setup code
      },
    
      // ...
    };
    
    function handleScroll(event) {
      const currentScrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
      const isScrollingUp = currentScrollTop < previousScrollTop.value; 
         
      // Update previous scroll position
      previousScrollTop.value = currentScrollTop;
    
      // Logic for conditional auto-scrolling (explained below)
    }
    </script>


Implement Conditional Auto-scrolling:

In the watchEffect, check both message length and scroll direction to
determine if auto-scrolling is necessary.
Only scroll to the bottom if:

there are new messages (as before).
the user is not actively scrolling up (isScrollingUp is false).





   watchEffect(
      () => {
        if (messages.value.length) {
          const chatEl = chatContainer.value;
          if (!isScrollingUp.value) { // Only scroll if not scrolling up
            chatEl.scrollIntoView({
              behavior: "smooth",
              block: "end"
            });
          }
        }
      },
      { flush: "post" }
    );



Thanks! Can you provide a code demo for testing?
